# How to repull image in kubernetes that is already cached?

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, containers

I am using kubernetes cluster with 20 worker node. I have set image pull policy as IfNotPresent to reduce creation time. Image is hosted on dockerhub.

When i update the image in dockerhub i need to clear cache from all 20 worker nodes. Currently i am doing docker pull  on all 20 worker nodes to update latest image.

Is there any kubernetes native solution or any other best industry solution to update image on all nodes?

Comment: the best industry solution is to use a unique tag for each deployed image.  change the image tag and k8s will handle the upgrade for you.  you only have this problem because you want to use the same tag even though the image changes.  Whatever the reason you think it's not worth explicitly versioning your image, you're wrong :P . Explicit versions are well work the effort of specifying them.

Comment: This should be an answer

Comment: Tnx @DanielFarrell, versioning image will solve this issue. Will try to implement that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the best industry solution is to use a unique tag for each deployed image. change the image tag and k8s will handle the upgrade for you. you only have this problem because you want to use the same tag even though the image changes. Whatever the reason you think it's not worth explicitly versioning your image, you're wrong :P . Explicit versions are well work the effort of specifying them

Comment: too bad this is down voted, because it's the right answer.  Either you use specific versions, you always pull, or you get strange versions.  If you `Always` pull your images, you still don't know what to roll back to if you should need to roll back.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, would be useful if people wouldn't downvote without giving any reason. Upvoted.

Comment: What if I have multiple front ends, where I want the nginx:mainline-alpine always pulled at deployment rollout? The image will be tagged after the app will be installed inside the container (foo-fe:1.2.3). But this won't solve the issue since the FROM image will be cached on the node, and Docker doesn't check if the contents of the public image are changed, until the tag is the same, even with "imagePullPolicy: Always". Using specific versions instead (FROM nginx:1.21.5-alpine) forces us to check every week for new image releases. If you don't have nightly scripts to solve this,delete cache

Comment: FROM applies to build time.  Good reasons to version build time dependencies notwithstanding, you can provide `--pull` to `docker build` so that it always checks for a new version.

Answer (score 6):

u need to use Always in ImagePullPolicy.  if so, whenever there is change in commit hash with a specific tag, K8S will pull again.  Remember to set rollingUpdate too.

Comment: Will imagePullPolicy=Always fully download an image even if it has not changed?

Answer (score 5):

It depends if you are versioning your image on Docker Hub.

It's strongly encouraged to version your images for few reasons.

- it's quicker to rollback in case of an issue, because you just change version number to previous
- all your pods will use the same version of the image

You can read about configuration of [Container Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) in Kubernetes documentation.

> The  [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)  and the tag of the image affect when the  [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)  attempts to pull the specified image.
>
> - `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`: the image is pulled only if it is not already present locally.
> - `imagePullPolicy: Always`: the image is pulled every time the pod is started.
> - `imagePullPolicy`  is omitted and either the image tag is  `:latest`  or it is omitted:  `Always`  is applied.
> - `imagePullPolicy`  is omitted and the image tag is present but not  `:latest`:  `IfNotPresent`  is applied.
> - `imagePullPolicy: Never`: the image is assumed to exist locally. No attempt is made to pull the image.
>
> **Note:**  To make sure the container always uses the same version of the image, you can specify its  [digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier), for example  `sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2`. The digest uniquely identifies a specific version of the image, so it is never updated by Kubernetes unless you change the digest value.
>
> **Note:**  You should avoid using the  `:latest`  tag when deploying containers in production as it is harder to track which version of the image is running and more difficult to roll back properly.
>
> **Note:**  The caching semantics of the underlying image provider make even  `imagePullPolicy: Always`  efficient. With Docker, for example, if the image already exists, the pull attempt is fast because all image layers are cached and no image download is needed.

Comment: Does the ifNotPresent policy checks if the digest is different although the tag is still the same?